# Typo in default SE system message

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase, system-message

At some point a typo was introduced into the default SE beta system message; it now reads **iteself** instead of **itself**. It exists in the Unix/Linux and CS Theory betas:

[image: Screenshot of the Unix/Linux system message]

[image: Screenshot of the CS Theory system message]

But not in the older TeX/LaTeX beta:

[image: Screenshot of the TeX/LaTeX system message]

I only checked the betas I have accounts on, so I'm not sure at exactly which point the message changed (there's a 15 day gap between TeX/LaTeX and Unix/Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went and fixed all those typos.  There were a goodly number of them.

Comment: Thanks, although you introduced a new one on the [Unix/Linux one](http://unix.stackexchange.com); the closing anchor tag is now `<a/>` instead of `</a>`

Comment: @Michael - that'll teach me to type.  Fixed now.